# Cannot set ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled to a Binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I've had a day full of Silverlight idiosynchrasies, including this little doozy:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Second</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The above fails with:

```
  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
    Message=Set property '' threw an exception. [Line: 88 Position: 52]
    LineNumber=88
    LinePosition=52
    StackTrace:
         at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
    InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
         Message=Cannot set read-only property ''.
         StackTrace:
              at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
              at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
         InnerException:
```

If I change `{Binding IsEnabled}` to simply `True` or `False`, then it works fine.

I'm utterly confused because `ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled` is a `DependencyProperty` and is *not* readonly, so the error message is complete rubbish.

Any ideas how to fix this? Ultimately, all I want to do is have the `IsEnabled` property on the `ComboBoxItem`s to be bound to a property on my view model.

PS. Yes, I also tried binding `ItemsSource` to my view model collection and ensuring that the `IsEnabled` property actually existed on my view models. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this for now by overriding `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` as follows:

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

    // can't do this in ItemContainerStyle because SL is poo
    (element as ComboBoxItem).SetBinding(ComboBoxItem.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("IsEnabled"));
}
```

Is this really still not possible in SL4? Seems completely ridiculous to me, as have all the other problems I've run into today.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is way off base (and way late) but could it have to do with the naming of the property on the bound object matching the property you are setting?

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

Can you do it in XAML if the path isn't `IsEnabled`?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old but today I faced the same problem and I just want to confirm that what Dave Lowther suggested is the problem of this case.
After changing property name from `IsEnabled` to `IsComboBoxItemEnabled` everything started working properly, so just don't use `IsEnabled` name in your model